# Approach to Deal with 5 million Records Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I need to process more than 5 to 6 million financial records where each record is a transaction.

This is a Spring , Hibernate solution.

I can list below four Steps to make my background clear

1. Read each record in the table. Example (Salary)
2. Access only particular two columns (primary key field -ID) , (Salary - encrypted value with RSA)
3. Decrypt the salary field belongs to salary id.
4. Encrypt again with new security key.

   Solution needs to be done as a background process (may be spring Thread Pool Task Executor) system has to be up 24 * 7.

   Each record is a transaction , so what is the best way to load the records to process ? 
   Please provide me a example link if possible.

   I think best practice would be load 10 records , and then load next 10. How to implement such a solution with spring , hibernate.

Comment: Is using Hibernate a must?

Comment: You should have a look at JOOQ.

Comment: You could use Hibernate, but you'll have to make sure to use a stateless session, or flushing the session on a regular basis as explained in the [manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#batch-update). I would simply use JDBC for this.

Comment: If there are just those two columns and you are not allowed to lock the whole table for duration of update, how does one know which key should be used for decryption?

Answer (score 0):

I would forget entity frameworks as hibernate for such work and stick to the database side. (If you do not have other work to do during a transaction, ie. Mail sending, auditing, etc... where the code is only available on the server side)

Create a stored procedure doing the job and run it once during a known low-load time. Done in 5 to 30min.

Or, create a stored procedure taking one row at a time and run it through a (database) job with some delay so the performance is not impacted.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Quartz for the scheduled job, it's easy to integrate with spring and worked well for me in the past. To access the DB I agree with

> You could use Hibernate, but you'll have to make sure to use a
>   stateless session, or flushing the session on a regular basis as
>   explained in the manual. I would simply use JDBC for this. - JB Nizet

Answer (score 0):

my approach would be :

1. JPA And Hibernate to manage my Entities
2. Let Spring manage  Session and transactions
3. Spring Data if needed (optional)
4. Create a service To run my logic
5. Spring Batch -- Accustomed job : Step : Auto wire the service to the reader and the  writer.Use the processor to run an extra logic if needed.
6. Configure a job Launcher
7. Schedule the launcher to be executed
8. Synchronize it with Cron for example you can run the task every hour or 30 minutes 24/7 ..
9. you can use Thread Pool Task Executor

Plan different scenarios and different jobs so if a job fail you can run another logic

Comment: if I use Spring batch can I re-try particualr record in case of fail ?

Comment: yes you can, you can configure your job/step to treat each record separately then you can manage fails like runtime exceptions.

Comment: this is parallel thread processing how to avoid scenarios that two threads not process the same row. ?

Comment: transactional with a readCommited Isolation, this will prevent the threads from using dirty reads.